# C# thread disappear and finally block not executed

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, plc

I have a C# app to handle PLC (Siemens cpu that controls hardware devices) events. All events are handled in a separate thread, and all these threads are a big try/catch/finally block to lock database and then finally release the lock. It runs well until I put a Thread.Sleep() to avoid handling duplicate PLC events (as sometimes PLC triggers an event but data is still not updated so I want to sleep 1 second if I found data is same as previous data).

I put some logs to debug this problem and I found the handling thread disappeared without running the finally block. The thread main() is like this:

```cs
virtual protected void Thread1Main()
{
    DB.DeviceLock(config.position);
    if (config.position == 4)
        Logger.I("DeviceLock 4");
    try
    {
        if (_exchange.plc_long > 0 && _exchange.plc_short > 0 && _exchange.plc_long == _last_long && _exchange.plc_short == _last_short)
        {
            _last_long = 0;
            _last_short = 0;
            if (config.position == 4)
                Logger.I("Before sleep 4");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (config.position == 4)
                Logger.I("After sleep 4");
            return;
        }
        _last_long = _exchange.plc_long;
        _last_short = _exchange.plc_short;
        .......
        if (config.position == 4)
            Logger.I("end 4");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (config.position == 4)
            Logger.I("exception 4");
        Logger.E(this, ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (config.position == 4)
            Logger.I("finally 4");
        DB.DeviceUnlock(config.position);
        _thread = null;
    }
}
```

Here I have DB.DeviceLock() which locks only this device, and I have DBLock() which locks all devices. DB code is like this:

```cs
static public void DBLock()
{
    Logger.I("DBLock:Before lock");
    lock (_locker)
    {
        while (_deviceLocks.MyCount() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var d in _deviceLocks.MyToArray())
                Logger.W($"DBLock:Wait device {d} to unlock");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        };
        _dbLock = 1;
        Logger.I("DBLock:Locked");
    }
}

static public void DBUnlock()
{
    Logger.I("DBLock:Unlocked");
    _dbLock = 0;
}

static public void DeviceLock(int d)
{
    lock(_locker)
    {
        while (_dbLock > 0)
        {
            Logger.W($"DBLock:Device {d} waiting DBLock");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        };
        _deviceLocks.MyAdd(d);
    }
}

static public void DeviceUnlock(int d)
{
    _deviceLocks.MyRemove(d);
    if (_deviceLocks.MyCount() > 0)
        Logger.W($"DBLock:released {d}, still locked: " + string.Join(",", _deviceLocks.MyToArray()));
}
```

And in log when I deliberately put suspect data to make it sleep -> handle -> sleep -> handle, I do see correct logs, even when the finally block is executed:

```
I 16:58:47.798 :DeviceLock 4
I 16:58:47.798 :Before sleep 4
I 16:58:48.799 :After sleep 4
I 16:58:48.799 :finally 4
I 16:58:48.834 :DeviceLock 4
W 16:58:48.842 :DB locks:released 701, still locked: 4
I 16:58:48.848 :end 4
I 16:58:48.848 :finally 4
I 16:58:48.935 :DeviceLock 4
I 16:58:48.935 :Before sleep 4
```

The problem is when I call DBLock(), everything stops. DBLock keeps waiting for device 4 to unlock, but device 4 thread disappeared! It never comes back again, its finally block is not executed, and in debug mode, I can't find that thread in visual studio's thread view. Log  becomes like this:

```
I 16:58:52.355 :DeviceLock 4   <-- this is the last log of device 4
I 16:58:53.766 :DBLock:Before lock
W 16:58:53.766 :DBLock:Wait device 4 to unlock
W 16:59:02.774 :DBLock:Wait device 4 to unlock
```

and then endless

```
W 16:59:02.774 :DBLock:Wait device 4 to unlock
```

So my question is: Why does the thread disappear without running finally block?

Added more info:

I found this code is probably causing problem:

```cs
public void RefreshAlertIcon(Device dev,int error)
{
    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        if (_d2icon.ContainsKey(dev.config))
            _d2icon[dev.config].ShowAlert(error > 0 && !_d2icon[dev.config]._alert);
    }
    else
        Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate {
            if (_d2icon.ContainsKey(dev.config))
                _d2icon[dev.config].ShowAlert(error > 0 && !_d2icon[dev.config]._alert);
        });
}
```

RefreshAlertIcon is called in Thread1Main(), the ..... part. So Dispatcher is causing a thread to disappear, am I using Dispatcher correctly?

Comment: The simplest explanation is that some other thread changes `config.position` to some other value. I assume `DeviceLock` is intended to prevent that, but that might not work as intended. To see if this is the case, copy `config.position` to a local variable a check if it has the same value after the sleep.

Comment: Could you minimalize the code inside the question? You could remove everything that is not essential for demonstrating the problem, like all the `if (config.position == 4)`, provided that the problem still exists after the removal. Also please include the implementation of all the non-standard APIs that you are using, like `MyCount` and `MyToArray`, or replace them with the corresponding standard APIs. We can't debug code that we can't even see.

Comment: What is the type of the application (WinForms, Console app etc), and what is the targeted .NET platform? (.NET 7, .NET Framework etc)

Comment: Your code looks like a race condition in the making. I'd love to see the actual library that you're using, how to pull values from the PLC, and what the duplicate situation is. I think we could rewrite your code to be much clearer and easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that changing Dispatcher.Invoke to InvokeAsync solved the problem. It seems Dispatcher.Invoke has its own lock and probably can't be called from UI thread itself. So finally the code looks like:

```
    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(delegate {
        if (_d2icon.ContainsKey(dev.config))
            _d2icon[dev.config].ShowAlert(error > 0 && !_d2icon[dev.config]._alert);
    });
```

Our application now has been working continuously for 1 week without problem! Great!